# Erro MySQL connector/C

Tags: mysql, c

Estou com um problema em C, ao tentar incluir a livraria MySQL deu alguns erros estranhos que não achei em lugar algum.

Baixei a livraria no [site oficial](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/) para Win32-x86 (ZIP) e instalei no MinGW (32 bits, última versão com todos os componentes).

Já fiz as configurações de linker para a livraria e para o MinGW, compilei com o GNU GCC Compiler. Uso o CodeBlocks.

Build log:

```
-------------- Build: Debug in MySQL connector (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

mingw32-gcc.exe -Wall --- include/libmysql.def  Thu Jan 13 07:46:56 2005 -g  -c "C:\Users\User\Desktop\C scripts\MySQL connector\main.c" -o obj\Debug\main.o
mingw32-gcc.exe: error: include/libmysql.def: No such file or directory
mingw32-gcc.exe: error: Thu: No such file or directory
mingw32-gcc.exe: error: Jan: No such file or directory
mingw32-gcc.exe: error: 13: No such file or directory
mingw32-gcc.exe: error: 07:46:56: Invalid argument
mingw32-gcc.exe: error: 2005: No such file or directory
mingw32-gcc.exe: error: unrecognized command line option '---'
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
7 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
```

Comment: Você entrou com essa linha de comando na mão? Ou foi de algum script de build? Porque a mensagem de erro que o GCC aponta é única e exclusivamente relacionada aos argumentos.

Comment: Foi de um script.

Answer (score -1):

Problema resolvido. Removi as linhas de comando em Project -> Build Options -> Compiler settings -> Other compiler options.

Comment: Qual opção? Bote aqui para que outra pessoa que tenha o mesmo problema que o seu entenda sua resposta e seja capaz de replicar a solução